# How can I call different function

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin

I have a form:

`From Date: ...      To Date: ...    Vehicle Number: ...    button (show record) dropdownmenu`

I enter the dates (from and to) and vehicle number it select the record right when
I click on button, but now I want to do it that when I select another option from drop-down menu the form remains the same:

`From Date: ...      To Date: ...    Vehicle Number: ...    button (show record) drop-down menu`

when I click the button it will take only from Date field value and run another query and ignore to data and vehicle number.

In short: on select option of drop-down menu I will change the onClick event of button to 
run another query.

Comment: And the question is? Also, give the code you have so far...

Comment: I understand there's a language barrier, but your question is very unclear.

Comment: SELECT fare, commission, routecode, vehiclenumber, productcode as code, shipment._date as date, driver, ownername
FROM route, shipment, product, vehicle, owner
WHERE vehicle.vehicleid = shipment.vehicle 
AND shipment.product = product.productid
AND shipment.vehicle = vehicle.vehicleid         
AND shipment.source = route.routeid              
AND vehicle.owner = owner.ownerid 
and shipment._date='$frm_date'";
(i want it that one button run different queries depend on select option from dropdownmenu and the form is also same)

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what your asking, but if you want a certain  function to run on the selection of a select box option, why not use a onchange event on the select box?

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="runFunction(document.getElementById('mySelect').value);">
    <option value="myValue"></option>
    <option value="moreValues"></option>
    <option value="anotherValue"></option>
</select>
```

then the function can do different things depending on the values it has been passed
a simple example would be

```
function runFunction(option){
    if(option === "myValue"){
        Do something
    }
}
```